# Symfony - Join table API return

Tags: function, api, symfony, integer

I made two JOIN tables with fields and made an API call that should return and post integer values to the main (User) table but I can't get syntax right.

My Service..

```
 public function setUserTerms($id)
{
    $termsId = $this->getTermsRepository()->find($id);

    $termUsers = $this->getUserTermsRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('ut')
        ->select('ut')
        ->where('ut.termsId = :termsId')
        ->setParameter('termsId', $termsId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $termUsers;
}
```

My Controller..

```
public function getUserTermsAction()
{
    $this->requirePostParams([ 'id']);

    $id = $this->data['id'];

    $termsId = $this->container->get('app.configuration')->setUserTerms($id);

    return $this->success($termsId);
}
```

I got an error of "Missing params: id""

Comment: Needs a little more info, what's inside app.configuration. But I believe it should be $user->setAgreedTerm($term); You're applying it to user, not configuration right? Not enough information to give you exact answer I think.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I updated the code! I think I am on the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely looking for this logic :

In Controller :

```
$term_id = $request->request->get('id');

$term = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(UserTerms::class)->findOneBy(['termsId'=>$term_id);

if($term){
    $user->setTerm($term);
    $em->flush(); // Entity Manager 
}else{
//error, no term was found.
} 

// Success stuff
```

This requires you to have the proper "setTerm" function setup in your entity.

This is based on Symfony 4, I believe it applies to 3 as well.